Bitbucket python Multiple PR requests against the same branch
I am trying to create a python script that creates multiple PR merge request from different branchs towards the same main branch but get  the error. I am unsure why " HTTPError('Branch "" is already up-to-date with branch "" in repository "".')
from atlassian import Bitbucket  

src_branch_list = ['branch1','branch2','branch3','branch4']
project ="TestProject"
rep_name="EDI"
dest_branch_name="Main"
title= "test"
description= "test"
reviewers= "test"
for src_branch_name in src_branch_list 
       response = bitbucket.open_pull_request(project, repo_name, project, repo_name, src_branch_name, dest_branch_name, title, description,reviewers)

